# Python - Read Text File, Extract certain text strings

Tags: python

I'm new here and also new to python so I'm struggling with a simple task that i hope you can help me with.

I have a text file that contains data in the following format:

```
<add key="DateFormat" value="dd-MMM-yyyy"/>
<add key="JsDateFormat" value="DD-MMM-YYYY"/>
<add key="dbDateFormat" value="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"/>
```

What I want to do is to read and print the lines that contain certain keys, for example DateFormat and dbDateFormat and print their values.

I am reading files using:

```
f = open("file.config", "r")
file = f.read()
print(file)
```

It reads the whole file as expected, but I don't know how to make it search and print with the conditions described above.

I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print line containing "word" python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905101/print-line-containing-word-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657794/read-line-in-file-print-line-if-it-contains-string

Comment: And etc; what did you search for, what did you find; why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the document is a proper XML file or not. Your example content will raise parse error if I read using `lxml` library. So it is needed to be fixed at first. The following nodes must be children of a root node. Let's assume the root node is `<body>`.

```
from lxml import etree

text="""
<body>
<add key="DateFormat" value="dd-MMM-yyyy"/>
<add key="JsDateFormat" value="DD-MMM-YYYY"/>
<add key="dbDateFormat" value="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"/>
</body>
"""

parsed = etree.fromstring(text)

# Now applying xpath to get value

print(parsed.xpath("//add[@key='DateFormat']/@value"))

# Which outputs to ['dd-MMM-yyyy']
```

You can use `or` xpath expression to get values from the keys you want .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for an answer, i handled it with a simple for / if loop and parsed text strings, thanks anyway!